# Java Swing - BasicStroke smaller to the left

Tags: java, swing, border

I'm writing a simple 2D chess game with Java Swing but I have encountered a problem with `BasicStroke`: the left side is smaller than the right side.

[image: chess board image]

In the case of the image, the left side is smaller by 5 pixels (calculated with GIMP).

This is the class that realizes the interface

```java
public class ChessInterface extends JComponent
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private static final int CHESS_BOARD_SIZE = 500;
    
    // class for managing the chess board
    private Board board;

    private int pieceSize;
    
    // space to center the board
    private int space;
    
    private Image table;
    
    private Image cellDark, cellLight;

    private Map<String, Image> pieceImages;

    public ChessInterface(Board board)
    {
        this.board = board;
        pieceSize = CHESS_BOARD_SIZE / 8;
        // 800 is the parent size
        space = (800 - CHESS_BOARD_SIZE) / 2;
        try
        {
            table = ImageIO.read(ChessInterface.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/table.jpg"));
            cellLight = ImageIO.read(ChessInterface.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/wood_light.png"));
            cellDark = ImageIO.read(ChessInterface.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/wood_dark.png"));
            pieceImages = new HashMap<>();
            // pieces image are converted from .svg to .png with Batik
            board.getPieces().forEach(e -> {
                Image pieceImage = pieceImages.get(e.getImage());
                if (pieceImage == null)
                {
                    ImgTranscoder transcoder = new ImgTranscoder();
                    transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, (float) pieceSize);
                    transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, (float) pieceSize);
                    try (InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream(e.getImage()))
                    {
                        TranscoderInput trInput = new TranscoderInput(input);
                        transcoder.transcode(trInput, null);
                        pieceImage = transcoder.getImage();
                        pieceImages.put(e.getImage(), pieceImage);
                    }
                    catch (TranscoderException | IOException e1)
                    {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        RenderingHints qualityHints = new RenderingHints(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        qualityHints.put(
            RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2.setRenderingHints(qualityHints);
        
        // draw the wooden background
        g2.drawImage(table, 0, 0, null);
        
        // draw the rounded border
        Rectangle boardRectangle = new Rectangle(space, space, CHESS_BOARD_SIZE, CHESS_BOARD_SIZE);
        Stroke old = g2.getStroke();
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(100,BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
        g2.draw(boardRectangle);
        g2.setStroke(old);
        
        // draw cells and pieces
        for(int i=8; i>=1; i--)
        {
            for(char j='a'; j <= 'h'; j++)
            {
                Image cell = (i + j) % 2 == 0 ? cellDark : cellLight;
                Piece piece = board.getPiece(new Position(i,j));
                int x = space + pieceSize * (j - 'a');
                int y = space + pieceSize * (8 - i);
                g2.drawImage(cell, x, y, pieceSize, pieceSize, null);
                if (piece != null)
                    g2.drawImage(pieceImages.get(piece.getImage()), x, y, null);
            }
        }
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

I really don't know how to solve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). As an aside, why custom paint a chess board? See [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556) for a way to create the board using components. The view above could be achieved by adding a Swing `Border` to the chess board panel.

Comment: I doubt the left side is smaller. I would guess your math for centering the chessboard is wrong. Start by 1) just painting the background, then 2) paint the Border to make sure it is centered and then 3) paint the chessboard so it is centered

Comment: @camickr I did the three steps and you're right: my math is wrong. The board covers the border so that's the reason the left border is smaller. Now I'm trying to find a solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31150700/7363182)

This is my code

```java
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        
    RenderingHints qualityHints = new RenderingHints(
        RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    qualityHints.put(
        RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2.setRenderingHints(qualityHints);
        
    g2.drawImage(table, 0, 0, null);
    
    int borderWidth = 20;
    
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.fillRoundRect(space - borderWidth, space - borderWidth, CHESS_BOARD_SIZE +
        borderWidth * 2, CHESS_BOARD_SIZE + borderWidth * 2, 20, 20);
        
    for(int i=8; i>=1; i--)
    {
        for(char j='a'; j <= 'h'; j++)
        {
            Image cell = (i + j) % 2 == 0 ? cellDark : cellLight;
            Piece piece = board.getPiece(new Position(i,j));
            int x = space + pieceSize * (j - 'a');
            int y = space + pieceSize * (8 - i);
            g2.drawImage(cell, x, y, pieceSize, pieceSize, null);
            if (piece != null)
                g2.drawImage(pieceImages.get(piece.getImage()), x, y, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Result

[image: chess board image]